# header() place & validation of a custom HTTP 404 page with chrome inspection network tab

Tags: php, http-headers, http-status-code-404

I redirect all url requests to index.php

after analyzing the URI, I set my `$requested_page` variable and set the proper includes.

I utilize the approach below (simplified):

```
include 'header.inc.php'; // constant for all pages (even for 404 page)

if ( $requested_page == '404'  ) {        
    include '404content.inc.php';        
}
if ( $requested_page == 'other'  ) {        
    include 'othercontent.inc.php';        
}

include 'footer.inc.php'; // constant for all pages (even for 404 page)
```

**404content.inc.php**

```
<?php
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'] = 404;
?>
<p>Page could not be found!</p>
```

After I tried a non-existing page and displayed it in chrome network inspection tab, related output image is below.

**QUESTION 1**

I am not sure that whether I must send the two `header()` commands at the beginning of `header.inc.php` OR in the `404content.inc.php` (my current coding case)

**QUESTION 2**

Is this a enough evident that I set my 404 page correctly? I don't know any other validation method. Are those status code 200 and canceled normal? (code 200 are css and logo.png; the canceled one is modernzr.js.)

## EDIT:

if I send `header()` commands at the very beginning of `header.inc.php`, then the `200 OK` status **become** `304 Not Modified`.

thanks in advance

best regards

[image]